# Sorting issues for Pagination sorting in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, rails-postgresql

For pagination sorting am geting duplicated data once load the next page.
For Eg: if a we have full name: Ahern in 1st page and after moving next page also sometimes we can able to see the same record.
I need accurate data for each time for sorting a specific field.
Am using order by as : ORDER BY Hourse :: numeric ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50

Please suggest an accurate sorting method using in postgres sql.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use SQL `LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` as pagination for PostgreSQL you need to add ordering by unique value. Seems `Hourse :: numeric` is not unique over the table.

If you have an unique ID column, I would recommend to add this column as a second ordering argument, like `ORDER BY Hourse :: numeric ASC, id ASC`

PS. There is a brilliant article about Postgresql pagination tricks https://www.citusdata.com/blog/1872-joe-nelson/409-five-ways-paginate-postgres-basic-exotic